# Reconfiguring Apache Camel route parameters at runtime

Tags: apache-camel

I have aggregation configured in my code:

```
.aggregate(new BodyAggregationStrategy())
    .constant(true)
    .completionSize(1000)    // Static value
    .completionTimeout(300)  // Static value
```

After I have started the Apache Camel context is it possible to change various parameters like **completionSize** and **completionTimeout** values?

When context is running a lot of data are transfering throught it and I want to increase some parameters like queue size and so on.

Answer (score 2):

What you could do, is via the CameContext

- stop the route
- remove the route
- add the route with new parameters
- start the route

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to connect via [JMX](https://camel.apache.org/camel-jmx.html#CamelJMX-Whichendpointsareregistered) and see if those parameters can be configured?